# What is the maven command for build Apache Felix - OSGi - framework project?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

In this Wiki it seems I can get answered my question but it seems not been updated since 2013

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FELIX/Building+Felix

They say:

`mvn -Dpackaging=plugins install"` 
and then
`mvn -Dpackaging=bundle install`

I just tried this script at the root directory of my cloned [felix-dev](https://github.com/apache/felix-dev) repository, in order to build all maven projects behind it; and it seems to work well, except for the need to replace `<source>1.5</source>` and `<target>1.5</target>` for `1.7` in many `pom.xml`

```
for D in $( find * -maxdepth 0 -type d ); do
    if ! [[ "$D" =~ .*/pom ]];
    then
    echo ".......... proceed to build $D?"
    #read
    cd $D
    mvn clean
    mvn -Dpackaging=plugins install
    mvn -Dpackaging=bundle install
    fi
    done
```